# CS0426 - The type name { } does not exist in the type { }

Tags: c#, wpf

Today I worked at my project and suddenly the following error ris:

> CS0426    The type name '**CustomerView**' does not exist in the type '**PetrolStation**'

I have no clue what is going on here:

[image: My Solution in VisualStudio]

I think that image shown above is pretty self explaining. You may notice that the same error happens also a code-block further down with the error:

> CS0426    The type name '**Views**' does not exist in the type '**PetrolStation**'

And the same error here again:

[image: My Solution in VisualStudio]

Which raises the following error:

> CS0426    The type name '**App**' does not exist in the type '**PetrolStation**'

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add a class called `PetrolStation` to your namespace `PetrolStation`?

Comment: "I worked at my project" and "out of nowhere" are contradictory statements.

Comment: Have you created a new class somewhere with the same name as the namespace? Right click on `PetrolStation` and click `Go to definition`

Comment: Ahh Okey, this seems to be the Problem thanks, @Clemens

Comment: Clean and rebuild

Comment: Clean and rebuild doesn't fix compilation errors

Comment: this also happens when you're adding a reference of a service in the "service" project itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your class is defined in `PetrolStation` namespace then you shouldn't specify this namespace while accessing to this class. Delete `PetrolStation` namespaces before class names:

```
App app = new App(); //and in other places without PetrolStation
```

**OR**

If your class name is the same as namespace name then you should specify full name:

```
PetrolStation.PetrolStation.App app = new PetrolStation.PetrolStation.App(); //and in other places with one more PetrolStation
```

It seems to be the first case in your code.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Type name does not exist in the type]

Please check while using the keyword new - the class name should end with `()`.

The wrong way to create an object:

```
new AssessmentEntryAccessMasterBL.HasAssessmentEntryRights
```

The right way to create an object:

```
new AssessmentEntryAccessMasterBL().HasAssessmentEntryRights
```

[image: Correct object creation code screenshot]